# always the same answer using simple math

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  long double luc = 3.156E+7;
   long double age;
    long double seconds = age * luc;
    printf("insert age here:\n");
    scanf("%Le", &age);
    printf("Hello world! %Le\n", seconds);
    return 0;
}
```

I am just starting to learn C in college and our first assignment is to make a program that will do basic math. i feel like my code is not mistaken, but when i display "*" or "+", i get an answer that is way off.  for example, i entered 2 for each variable and i got -2.0000 the first time and some random number the second time. what could be causing this?

Comment: If you are just learning, why are you using scanf?  http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: if you do each line one after another then 1) `luc` is assigned `3.156E+7` 2) `age` is assigned a completely random indeterminate value, 3) `seconds` is assigned the product of `age` (some random value) and `luc` (`3.156E+7`), 4) `age` is read in from the keybboard and then 5) the previously calculated balue of `seconds` is printed.

Comment: So i got to always put all things in order thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `age` variable **before** you have read in its value! Move the declaration (or at least, the *calculation*) of `seconds` to after the `scanf` call:

```c
int main()
{
    long double luc = 3.156E+7;
    long double age;
    long double seconds;
    printf("insert age here:\n");
    scanf("%Le", &age);
    seconds = age * luc;
    printf("Hello world! %Le\n", seconds);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hello Adrian Mole i try to do the way you`ve done but still doesnt works, it gives the same answer -2.0000. And doesnt matter the number i input it just gives the same answer. I am using codeblocks do you think its the compiler?

Comment: ```#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  float luc = 3.156E+7;
   int age;
   float seconds;
    printf("insert age here:\n");
    scanf("%d", &age);
   seconds = age * luc;
    printf("Hello world %e\n", seconds);
    return 0;
}``` i think i solved the problem by doing this way, but i dont now why didnt work with long double

Comment: It's possible your compiler doesn't support `long double`. But, in your code, you must **not** use the `%d` format in `scanf` for `float` - use `%f`. Try with just `double` and use `%le` or `%lf` or `%lg` as the format (lowercase `l`). (Did you maybe have `%d` in your `long double` test? That would break the code, for sure.) @fabinsky33

Comment: thank you, it worked the way you said but how can i use long double in my compiler and whats "break the code"?  by the way thank you for your time helping me :)

Comment: If you use the wrong format specifier in your `scanf` call (e.g. `%d` for a `double` or `long double`) then you can expect all sorts of horrible things to happen. This is what I meant by "break the code!"